# Android - How to Run Multiple Threads in Parallel

Tags: java, android, multithreading, email, parallel-processing

I am developing an android application that synchronizes the user's emails using Gmail API.

To do so i have implemented two services where the first is for downloading the Unread Emails and the second is for downloading Read Emails. Each service implements the Runnable interface and the code for retrieving the emails and storing them in the database is handled using a thread inside the Run() method.

Everything works fine the only problem i have is that when the Thread responsible for downloading the Read Emails is running (which takes longer than the other) the second Thread (Sync unread emails) is blocked until the first one is completed.

I would like to know if there is anyway that i can prioritize the second Thread over the first one so whenever the first one is running and the second thread have to run, the code should put the second thread on hold until the first one (Unread emails) complete running and then resume the thread on hold.

Regards.

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to create a second service that runs for just a short time i would suggest you to study the AsyncTask, but if you are looking to create a service that runs constantly you would need to use the java.util.concurrent API(Executor, ThreadpoolExecutor). Wish i helped, but with a few readings you can pick up more knowledge about multithreaded applicarions. Tell me if you need more help!

Comment: Actually the Thread responsible for getting the Read emails have to run every 1 hours but the other one for getting the UnRead emails have to run every 1 minute. Now my code executes the 1 minute thread and then executes the other one (much longer) the problem is when the longer one is running and the shorter one is ready to run it's blocked and have to wait until the first one finishes which takes forever and that's not what i want. I want to put the longer one on hold until the shorter one run and finish. is that possible? if yes how? Thank you.

Comment: It seems folish to run a process to download read emails every hour. It wastes to much data. Instead i would suggest to start that download old emails thread on a button click. But if you wana follow the logic you have started i would suggest trying out ExecutorService and messing with its properties. A solution can be found!

Comment: Downloading old emails on button click is a good idea but it won't work well when the user have so many emails (it will take too long to finish and update the UI) but thanks anyway. can you please post a snippet code of how to handle my issue using the ExecutorService ? many thanks.

Comment: Sure, but its nearly midnight at where i live and i'm using my iPad. Tomoorow morning i would not mind giving you some short codes! You are wellcome

Comment: Thank you for your help i appreciate that.